# How to disable Ctrl+F search window at integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Do you know how to disable Search window showing up at integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code when "Ctrl-F" is pressed?
With this, I am forced to press arrow button to use completion by fish shell.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Gear Icon/Keyboard Shortcuts page find the

`Terminal: Focus Find` command, right -click and choose `Remove Keybinding`

That will add the following keybinding to the end of your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+f",
  "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.focusFind",
  "when": "terminalFindFocused && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFindFocused && terminalProcessSupported || terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
},
```

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will no longer bring up the terminal find widget.

Comment: I think it's better to open the shortcuts UI and search for "ctrl+f" manually and right click and select "remove keybinding" because as time passes the value of `when` in your answer may vary from versions to versions.